# Send mail through SMTP using OAuth 2

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I need to send a SMTP mail through OAuth 2. I have created some code to get a token but got the following error response:

> Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:

Code:

```cs
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("folder/serviceaccountgenratedcredecialfile.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("service-account-email@my-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                     {
                         Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
                         User = "user-email@gmail.com"
                     }.FromCertificate(certificate));

bool result = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

For example `Gmail`:

```
void SendMailWithXOAUTH2(string userEmail, string accessToken)
{
    try
    {
        // Gmail SMTP server address
        SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");
        // enable SSL connection
        oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
        // Using 587 port, you can also use 465 port
        oServer.Port = 587;

        // use Gmail SMTP OAUTH 2.0 authentication
        oServer.AuthType = SmtpAuthType.XOAUTH2;
        // set user authentication
        oServer.User = userEmail;
        // use access token as password
        oServer.Password = accessToken;

        SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
        // Your gmail email address
        oMail.From = userEmail;
        oMail.To = "support@emailarchitect.net";

        oMail.Subject = "test email from gmail account with OAUTH 2";
        oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project with gmail.";

        Console.WriteLine("start to send email using OAUTH 2.0 ...");

        SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();
        oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);

        Console.WriteLine("The email has been submitted to server successfully!");
    }
    catch (Exception ep)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ep.Message);
    }
```

Using Client ID and Client secret to get access token.
Now you can use client id and client secret to get the user email address and access token. Basically, OAUTH uses HTTP protocol, first of all, user inputs user and password in Google Web Authentication, Google returns access token back to your application, finally, your application uses the access token to access `Gmail SMTP server`. You can find the example codes in `EASendMail` Installation Path\Samples_{Programming language/Developer Tool}\GmailOauth.* project.

You must apply for your client id and client secret, don't use the client id in the sample project, because it is limited now. If you got "This app isn't verified" information, please click `"advanced" -> Go to ...` for the test.

Comment: I need the accessToken how can you get the accessToken ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the only authentication way supported by smtp is basic auth (user/password). If you want to use auth you should consider using ews (Exchange Web Service).

Answer (score -2):

```
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com"); //From Email Id
        mailMessage.Subject = Subj; //Subject of Email
        mailMessage.Body = Message; //body or message of Email
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        List<string> ToEmailList = ToEmail.Split(',').ToList();
        ToEmailList.ForEach(x => mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(x.ToString())));
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net", 25);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = "abc@abc.com",
            Password = "abc@001"
        };
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Bhanu Pratap i think this is not  used OAuth 2